# Can I connect this meter to 220vac?

Tags: analog, meter

Can I connect this analog meter directly to 220VAC without any additional components?

And what is the meaning of writing on the right?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can connect anything to 220VAC, some things even multiple times ;) Seriously, though, we can't tell from the front – probably, yes, but this might also just be a meter with a face printed with a scale, to be used with some measurement transformer. Data's probably on the back, or in the datasheet.

Comment: That model is selling on Alibaba for $1.20 to $1.50 each in quantities of 500. Your chances of finding a datasheet are zero, I expect. From your photo the front cover has fallen off and the exposed components would be at mains potential. I would bin it.

Comment: The second photo only makes it worse. No label and terminals marked + and - on an AC meter.

Comment: @Marcus, good joke! I added a photo of the meter's back..

Comment: @Transistor, I extracted it from a broken automatic voltage regulator, I removed the front cover for the purpose of giving you a clear image

Comment: It's a class 5.0 meter, so pretty crappy. The meter sells for $1 (Y7) quantity 1 in China with free domestic shipping. https://i.imgur.com/tgEwNw7.png It's not very safe if the cover comes off easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 91L16 Series 40mm x 40mm moving coil AC voltmeter, with rectifier, intended for direct connection across mains.

It's accuracy class is +/- 5% of full scale deflection.

All specifications are symbolically marked on the dial.

Here's a list of the symbols generally marked on panel meter dials.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, as usual, perfect answer.

Comment: @Shaydzmi, You are most welcome! - Nandu.

Comment: Thank you, Shaydzmi.

Answer (score 7):

The internal 150 kΩ resistor and diode suggest that it is indeed intended to be connected directly to the AC line, but the actual construction would not meet any modern safety standards!

The average value of a half-wave rectified sine wave is 0.45 times the RMS value, so at 220 Vrms, there will be about 0.66 mA flowing through the meter, which corresponds to 2/3 of full-scale on a 1-mA movement, consistent with the labeling on the face.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this meter will work (approximately) correctly when connected to your AC Mains supply. The proper way to find out is to use something like a Variac and slowly increase the voltage applied while observing the meter.

I base this opinion on the fact that there is a rectifier plus resistor of value 150k in series with the meter movement.

I say "approximately" because these meters are notoriously inaccurate.

Comment: *"these meters are notoriously inaccurate"* They are also underdamped and have a horrible mechanical overshoot problem, when the power is on, the needle can oscillate for 15 seconds before settling down, but good enough for a cheap Variac...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this device is a *moving-coil ammeter* (meter movement). The resistor in series to it acts as a *voltage-to-current converter*. So the combination of them acts as a *DC voltmeter*. The diode in series makes it an *AC voltmeter*.

The bare movement has polarity; hence these "+" and "-" on the back. Obviously, the resistor and diode are added later. Note this is still a DC meter that has polarity (there is no blocking capacitor).

Answer (score 1):

The meter is "intended" to be an AC volt meter with up to 300 VAC input.
It's super cheap and nasty and should only be used in applications where users are either protected against any risk of shock or fire, if then.

[HERE](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Analoge-type-Panel-Meter-300VAC-48x45mm_942568865.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.55.3f6153d9rRWInp) is one of many examples of the meter for sale.
They specify it as 300 VAC, as you'd hope :-)

[image]

Also for sale [here](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/91L16-AC-0-to-300V-Volt_60521001274.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.45.3f6153d9rRWInp)

and [here](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/pointer-type-VU-voltage-panel-meter_60839470850.html?spm=a2700.7724857.normalList.34.3f6153d9rRWInp) where it is described as a
"pointer type VU voltage panel meter moving coil structure AC voltmeter 91L16  40*40mm" :-) :-(