# What is the meaning of numbers at bottom of electrical gauges?

Tags: measurement, gauge

I work in a power generation plant and I noticed that all the gauges have some kind of standard description at the bottom.

[image: Example]

Some of them are easy to understand (I strongly suspect "~" means alternative), and I think the voltage here (220V) is the input voltage, but in general is there a guide to understand all those symbols? I searched on google, but I think I didn't use the right terminology because I didn't find anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://www.marineeto.we.bs/2020/05/08/symbols-in-analog-measuring-meter-meaning-of-it/

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, that's exactly the type of reference I was looking for!

Comment: If you work at a power plant, can you get some on-the-job training on these meters? (I'd surely hope so!)

Comment: You have an answer here though the question is different. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494092/can-i-connect-this-meter-to-220vac/494142#494142